# Prove continuity of $f$ where $f(1,1) = 0$ and $f(x,y)= \frac{xy(1-x)(1-y)}{1-xy}$ for $(x,y)\ne(1,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity

I am given a multivariable function $f:[0,1]^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, such that

$f(x,y)= \begin{cases} 
      \ 0 & (x,y)=(1,1) \\
      \frac{xy(1-x)(1-y)}{1-xy} & otherwise \\
   \end{cases}$

How can I prove that it is continuous? Obviously, the only case I should do is find the value of $f$ as $(x,y)$ approaches $(1,1)$. So far I've tried doing it with $\varepsilon, \delta$ definition of the limit, then substitution in hopes that any factor of the fraction would cancel out, but both attempts were unsuccessful. Any hint would be appreciated!

Small edit: generally I would like to know what are the most common methods of showing that a multivariable function is continuous?

Edit 2: I made a typo in the first version ( I wrote $1$ instead of $0$ )

Comment: It seems that $f(1-1/n,1-1/n) \to 0\not=f(1,1)$ as $n \to \infty$ (check). This would mean that $f$ is not continuous in $(1,1)$.

Comment: The most common way to prove that a function is continuous at $(x_0,y_0)$ in my opinion is to bound it by something and show that that something tends to the value $f(x_0,y_0)$ However most of the times it iyou might want to choose first a smart path for  y to show that the function is not continuous

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact $f(x,y) \to 0$ as $(x,y) \to (1,1)$ since
$$
|f(x,y)| \le \frac{xy(1-xy)(1-xy)}{1-xy}=xy(1-xy) \quad ((x,y) \in [0,1]^2\setminus \{(1,1)\}).
$$

Answer (score 2):

You cannot prove that $f$ is continuous, since it isn't. Note that\begin{align}\lim_{x\to1}f(x,x)&=\lim_{x\to1}\frac{x^2(1-x)^2}{1-x^2}\\&=\lim_{x\to1}\frac{x^2(1-x)}{1+x}\\&=0\\&\ne1.\end{align}

Comment: i edited the question now!

Comment: I see. I've answered your question and then you replace it with another question to which my answer doesn't apply anymore. Don't you see a problem there?

Comment: @mikasas wife José Carlos Santos is right, you should mention this alteration in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you have to prove it is continuous?
In order for the function to be continuous at $(1,1)$:

\begin{align*}
\lim_{(x,y)\to(1,1)}{f(x,y)}=f(1,1)=1 \ \ \ \forall x,y
\end{align*}
Now let us choose $y=\frac{1}{x^2}\to 1$ as $x\to 1$. We have:

\begin{align*}
\lim_{(x,y)\to(1,1)}{f(x,\frac{1}{x^2}}=\lim_{x\to 1}{x(1-\frac{1}{x^2})}=0\neq f(1,1)
\end{align*}

Hence $f$ is not continuous